# List View with Slider Selector like IOS

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I need to make list view with Slider in the center, which remains fixed when the list view is scrolled. I am unable to understand which layout should be used for this type of slider in the center.

[image]

Comment: Awesome @Divyesh. Have you read what I have asked for ?

Comment: yes. and make center position fixed and when number is scroll and reach center. get that number and show it above

Comment: @Divyesh You are AWESOME

Comment: Refer these  libraries https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker & https://github.com/vanniktech/VNTNumberPickerPreference

Comment: is it worked?..

Comment: @Divyesh Do you think so ?

Comment: yes. it should be. and when it reach change its style

Comment: @mdg5435 Thanks. Yes it helpful